# Asp.net create function Student of the day

Tags: asp.net, arrays, timer

Im working on a ASP.net web application about my class.

All students have their own webform site with an own link refering to thier page.

But I´m trying to do a function for the homepage "student of the day".

I know that i have to put all student links in an array and randomize them.

My problem is that i want the studentlink to change every 24 hours.

How can I make a timer to pick a new object from the array.

Cheers

Comment: A `Timer` sounds like the wrong approach.  ASP.NET web applications aren't suited for background tasks, nor does this even need to be a background task.  If you can use a database, create a table for the student of the day and store a new record each day.  Any time the page is loaded, fetch the record for that day.  If one isn't found, randomly select from the list of students and create the record before displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with the comment that has been posted, however I am going to assume that you dont have a database at the moment, or you would alreday be using that rather than an array...

I minght have missed something in your question but I think we can use the pseudo random number generator with a seed based on today to get the "Random Number"

```
//I am assumung that you already have an array of students created at this point.
Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Day);
int selectedStudent = Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(1, 6));
object student = studentArray[selectedStudent];
```

Because the seed is the same every time you should get the same result every time until the seed changes and that happens when the day changes.

Of course this will not work unless you create a new instance of rnd each time that you need to generate the number.

Hope this helps, if not let me know.

Comment: Just realised that your index will be 0 based, you will want to change that rnd.Next to (0, 5)